# How to make it go and play a frame on main timeline when movieclip finishes without using a button?

Tags: actionscript-2, movieclip, timeline, cs4

If I have a movieclip already in a frame how do I make it go and play another frame on the main timeline once the movieclip is finished without using a button

Comment: What sort of code/attempts have you tried already?  We can help provide solutions, but it would be better if we could see what you've already tried.

Answer (score 0):

On the last from of your movieclip, add a new keyframe and the following actionscript.

```
_root.gotoAndPlay(25);
```

or

```
root.gotoAndPlay("whateverFrameLabelName");
```